Ubuntu 24.04 mouse clicking issue
I have installed the 24.04 Ubuntu recently and using the Lenovo Qi 60.5cm (24 Inch) FHD IPS Monitor. The close, maximize, minimize or any window options which usually present at the total end of right side corner are not working. For making them to work i have to minimize the windows size then they are clickable. The mouse is working fine all other clicks are working fine only the right side part having issue.
Icons on the right side.
When i changed the resolution from actual 1920x1080 to 16:10(1680x1050) they are working without any issue(but the screen looks blurry and nor proper resolution for anyone).
Please help in this issue I have not faced this issue in my previous LTS version 22.04.
